# Dynamic SQL has the same column in the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am investigating a performance issue from a Dynamic SQL and I discovered that the resulting GROUP BY repeats the same column twice, such as :

```
GROUP BY TBL1.COL1, TBL2.COL2, TBL1.COL1
```

I checked the explain plans of the two samples, one having multiple `TBL1.COL1` in the GROUP BY and the one with just one `TBL1.COL1` and it seems the same.

Is there anything else I need to check for this?
I am thinking if this should be removed or I should keep it as it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Repeating column name multiple times in `group by` clause will have no impact on performance.

Comment: While the plans tell you it is not an issue for performance, it is an indication that there is something not quite right in the construction of the sql. Apart from the group by, which you found yourself to be irrelevant for performance, you haven't given us any information to help with the actual issue